# How to create a frame in wxPython across multiple monitors?

Tags: python, wxpython

I'm trying to create a frame in wxPython that extends across multiple screens. The setup in which I'm trying this consists of a monitor with 1366x768 plus another monitor in portrait mode with 1080x1920.

GetSystemMetrics(76) and GetSystemMetrics(77) from win32api result in 0 and -1144 to get the left top of the virtual screen area.

GetSystemMetrics(78) and GetSystemMetrics(79) give me the total virtual screen resolution of 2446x1920.

When I call the frame with pos = (GetSystemMetrics(76), GetSystemMetrics(77)) and size = (GetSystemMetrics(78), GetSystemMetrics(79)) for some reason it gives me a frame with the size of the first monitor only.

```py
import wx
from win32api import GetSystemMetrics

class SelectableFrame(wx.Frame):

    c1 = None
    c2 = None

    def __init__(self, parent, id, title, pos, size):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, title, pos, size, style=wx.NO_BORDER) 
        self.Show(True)
        self.ToggleWindowStyle(wx.STAY_ON_TOP)
        self.SetFocus()
        self.Raise()
        print(pos)
        print(size)

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MOTION, self.OnMouseMove)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_DOWN, self.OnMouseDown)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_UP, self.OnMouseUp)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_PAINT, self.OnPaint)

        self.SetCursor(wx.Cursor(wx.CURSOR_CROSS))

        self.alphaValue = 100
        self.SetTransparent(self.alphaValue)
        self.Maximize(True)

    def OnMouseMove(self, event):
        global x2, y2
        if event.Dragging() and event.LeftIsDown():
            self.c2 = event.GetPosition()
            x2 = self.c2.x
            y2 = self.c2.y            
            self.Refresh()

    def OnMouseDown(self, event):
        global x1, y1
        self.c1 = event.GetPosition()
        x1 = self.c1.x
        y1 = self.c1.y
        self.Refresh()

    def OnMouseUp(self, event):
        print(self.c1)
        print(self.c2)
        self.SetCursor(wx.Cursor(wx.CURSOR_ARROW))           
        self.Destroy()

    def OnPaint(self, event):
        if self.c1 is None or self.c2 is None: return

        bdc = wx.PaintDC(self)
        dc = wx.GCDC(bdc)
        dc.SetPen(wx.Pen('red', 1))
        dc.SetBrush(wx.Brush(wx.Colour(0, 0, 0), wx.TRANSPARENT))

        dc.DrawRectangle(self.c1.x, self.c1.y, self.c2.x - self.c1.x, self.c2.y - self.c1.y)

if __name__=="__main__":

    app=wx.App(redirect=False)
    selectionFrame2 = SelectableFrame(
            parent=None, 
            id=wx.ID_ANY, 
            title="", 
            pos=(GetSystemMetrics(76),GetSystemMetrics(77)), 
            size=(GetSystemMetrics(78), GetSystemMetrics(79))
            )
    selectionFrame2.Show(True)

    app.MainLoop()
```

How do I generate this frame in wxPython that extends across multiple monitors and set it up so that it works with any combination of monitors?

Comment: Try to remove the self.Maximize() call and see if it works...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
wx.Display.GetCount()
# then you can get the geometry for each display
d = wx.Display(0)
d.GetGeometry()
```

That should give you the real sizes and positions of the displays.

Comment: Thanks! I got it to work creating a frame for each display using your suggestion.

Comment: If the answer resolved your problem, please mark it as accepted (gray combo box under voting buttons at left side of the answer). This is considered polite on StackOverflow. Also some guys take care about tag statistics.